# environment variables access from another file in python

Tags: python, environment-variables

I have a file1.py where

```
import os
y=os.getenv("num")
print(y)
```

and another file file2.py

```
import os
os.environ["num"]="7"
```

Why is it returning the value `None` instead of `7`. please guide me?

I want to access env varibales values of file1.py from another file file2.py

Comment: Maybe this could answer your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52449602/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-virtualenv

Comment: Environment variables aren't *in* any file. They exist in memory, and their values are determined by what code you execute, which is affected by which files you execute as scripts and which files you import. So how exactly are you executing your code?

Answer (score 0):

There's a misconception here, `os.environ` refers to the environment of the process being run. So when you create a new environment variable with`os.environ["num"] = 7`, you only modify the environment of the current program (`file2.py`). When you try to access `"num"` from another process (`file1.py`), it does not exist.

If you want to store environment variables in a persistent way on your system, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61757061/get-and-set-env-vars-in-python-on-windows/61757725#61757725) (assuming you're on Windows).

Answer (score -1):

For file1.py use:

```
import os
os.environ['num'] = '7'
```

For file2.py use:

```
import os
y = os.environ.get('num')
print(y)
```